# Link server physical folder to sharepoint web folder

Tags: folder

I have a physical folder on a Sharepoint server located at `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\temp\`. I want this folder, and it's contents, to be available at the server root, eg: `http://intranet/temp/`. I can't figure out how to do this, any help?

Comment: Can you explain why you would want to do this as doing so severely limits your farm's scalability

Comment: I need to do this because I write files to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What particular reason would you need to do this? SharePoint provides these types of virtual folders already, and I bet then can satisfy your requirement as is.

If you're curious though, they are set up in IIS. Read here for more info: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/150/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis-7/

Comment: I need to do this because I write files to the server.

Comment: Which server? Remember your environment could very well be running across more than one web front end, with one at a time performing each web request. Write to the file system and chances are they will instantly go out of sync. If your application cannot be architected in a way that doesn't involve writing to a file system, then perhaps SharePoint isn't the best system for that particular operation. You could offshore that operation to another ASP.NET environment, and use SharePoint for the eventual delivery, through web services, for example.

Comment: Also, I think modifying the IIS configuration to include custom virtual file system directories might render your SharePoint environment as unsupportable. I'm not certain that it does, but it's something to consider and watch out for.

Comment: I needed to extract the attachment from an infopath form and so I figured out a way to do it using jQuery and a code behind C# form. The only way I know how to do simple file i/o with C# is to a filesystem. Sharepoint wasn't cooperating, so I wrote to the local filesytem of the server. If you know a way around this, then I would really appreciate it.

Comment: InfoPath isn't my strong point, but I would look at somehow putting the file into a Document Library using the C# Object Model. I found a blog post that does this in a workflow, might be of some help: http://spappdev.blogspot.com/2009/03/programatically-extract-attachments.html

Comment: Perhaps I should show [the post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685519/upload-infopath-attachment-to-sharepoint) with all my code.

Comment: Well in your code that you have there, instead of writing to it to a file, pass the bytestream to SPFileCollection.Add - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfilecollection.add.aspx

Comment: Actually, I managed to do it using the previous link. I took the decodedData variable and passed it in it's entirety to the request stream. Thanks!